# multiple floats in div scaling to height of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="ws_bullets">
  <a href="#" class="1 scrollup">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="2 scrollup">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="3 scrollup">4</a>
  <a href="#" class="4 scrollup">5</a>
  <a href="#" class="5 scrollup ">6</a>
  <a href="#" class="6 scrollup ">7</a>
  <a href="#" class="7 scrollup ">8</a>
  <a href="#" class="8 scrollup ">9</a>
</div>
```

class numbers have background-image set
scrollup just margin
ws_bullets is position:fixed; to right top

I'm trying to fit the div to window height to scale any way to do this javascript ?

Comment: oh and scrollup haves float: left so they stack

Comment: Apply 'bottom: 0' and 'top: 0' to .ws_bullets. Although i'm still not completely sure I understand what you're asking. Could you put your markup and styles into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: You cannot have a class name that starts with a number or is a number

Comment: Uh if it is position fixed, then simply put height: 100%; and remove margins and padding from body????